# Find the antiderivative of $\sqrt{3x-1} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the antiderivative of $\sqrt{3x-1} dx$.

I got $\frac{2}{3}(3x-1)^{3/2}+c$ but my book is saying $\frac{2}{9}(3x-1)^{3/2}+c$

Can some one please tell me where the $2/9$ comes from?

Comment: $3x=u \implies 3 dx=du \implies dx=\dfrac{1}{3}du$, one factor of $9$ is from  the substitution part and other onw *already* you have it.

Comment: Please [take a look at how I've edited your MathJax code](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/0ffd5431-ea72-4cef-969e-a32baed6c9fa/view-source); in particular, group multi-character superscripts and subscripts with `{...}` and use `\sqrt{}` for square root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\int \sqrt{3x-1}~dx=\int(3x-1)^{1/2}~dx
$$
Let $u=3x-1$, $du=3~dx$, so
$$
\int(3x-1)^{1/2}~dx=\frac{1}{3}\int u^{1/2}~du
$$
Add one to the power of $u$, and divide by the new power
$$
\int \sqrt{3x-1}~dx=\frac{1}{3}\int u^{1/2}~du=\frac{1/3}{3/2}u^{3/2}+c=\frac{2}{9}(3x-1)^{3/2}+c
$$

---

Your problem is that you need to take into consideration the derivative of $3x-1$, which means you need to divide by $3$, giving you the factor of $\frac{1}{3}$ missing from your answer.

As was suggested in the [comments of your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/397062/evaluate-int-dfrac1-sqrt1-x-dx#comment849871_397062), if you differentiate the answer that you got with the chain rule, then you'll see why you've made a mistake
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{2}{3}(3x-1)^{3/2}\right)=\frac{3}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3}(3x-1)^{1/2}\underbrace{\frac{d}{dx}(3x-1)}_{=3}=3\sqrt{3x-1}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I think all you missed was to divide by the inside derivative, that is the derivative of $3x - 1$

Answer (score 0):

It comes from $2/3$ from the power and $1/3$ from the coefficient at $x$.